# How to read the `<td>` values of a webpage `html` table?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a webpage, and when I view the source I get the following:

```
<td>
  <a href="www.example.com">Ryhanu Datta</a>
</td>

<td> daffodil</td>
<td> b2/24 </td>
```

How can I read the `<td>` values of a table on a webpage using `selenium-webdriver` in Ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information that goes between  and  is known as the table data. Here is a more fleshed out table, and the meanings:

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Table header for column 1</th>
     <th>Table header for column 2</th>
     <th>Table header for column 3</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>data in row 1, column 1</td>
     <td>data in row 1, column 2</td>
     <td>data in row 1, column 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>data in row 2, column 1</td>
     <td>data in row 2, column 2</td>
     <td>data in row 2, column 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>data in row 3, column 1</td>
     <td>data in row 3, column 2</td>
     <td>data in row 3, column 3</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

So you have the pair of tags for the table itself  .. , then the pair for the header or title  ... , and the pair of tags for each row  ... , and finally, the tag you are asking about is where the table data goes:  ... . It is really very simple.

Sorry about the half post. I was having some finger trouble, and my old mac was not cooperating either. CHEERS!

I've added this. It doesn't format really well in the comment. So you need the following code to load the page (assuming google.ca, for example), and then to find the tag:

```
driver.get "http://www.google.ca"
table_data = driver.find_element(:tag_name, "td")
```

Again, I worked out how to do this from [here](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations).

CHEERS. (I hope I understood you properly this time).

Comment: What you meant? i want to read the values inside the tag `<td>..</td>`

Comment: OOPS, as you can see in my edited post I was having finger troubles. Sorry.

Comment: Ohh! wish you to be cure earliest! but how to read the <td>  values using ruby `selenium-webdriver`?

Comment: Ok, I just looked up "selenium-webdriver" I hadn't noticed that you had tagged that, and it didn't appear before you edited your post. So here is what I found out: You first get your web page using for example: driver.get "http://www.google.com", assumeing that is the webpage you want, then to get the information you want by tag, you need to do this: table_row = driver.find_element(:tag_name, "tr"). I used this page (http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations) to figure out the information I gave you.

Comment: what this line `driver.find_element(:tag_name, "tr")` is giving?

Comment: My mistake, you wanted table data, not table row. See the edit in the answer. Now as to what it gives you, basically as I understand it you can loacte web element by "id, class name, tag name, link text, partial link text, css, XPATH, etc, etc). You've asked to locate the information for <td> ... </td>, that would be locating it by tag, so that is what I used. You can see all the other details on the web page that I linked to in my answer. CHEERS!

Answer (score 2):

Use mechanize gem
[click here](http://rubygems.org/gems/mechanize) to download mechanize gem

Comment: what is the syntax to do so in `mechanize`?

Comment: require 'mechanize'
agent = Mechanize.new;
agent.get("http://www.example.com");
agent.page.search("td");
Its so simple

Comment: would it give me the `<td>` values? you can put it your answer as well.

Comment: Yes it can.give me site if possible.let me see. I will scrape for you

Comment: Its a password protected,so I can't :(

Comment: I have seen the docs, but there is not an example with each module's method somtimes. So as newbie,can you tell me how to use the docs?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23046/discussion-between-vbslover-and-sagar-junnarkar)